# BTC early adopter - is there a way to recover my wallet from Mt Gox now?

Tags: wallet-recovery, mtgox

In 2011 I was mining BTC via BTCMine.com and having the results deposited into my wallet at Mt. Gox. I never had a local copy of the wallet file, and of course then there was the first hack, which released account details. So the deposits were stopped.

Then there was the bigger hack where Mt Gox lost a bunch of BTC and went bankrupt, and I got out of crypto entirely. At the time my wallet was too small to fret over and I assumed there was nothing for it. I haven't looked at any of that in a decade...

Now I see news that Mt Gox is close to finishing their court stuff and it made me go looking - and lo and behold the master ledger, according to BitPay's Insight tool, says my wallet still has my balance in it. But I only have the payment address, found in the old emails from Mt Gox and BTCMine.

Does anyone know if there's a chance to get access to the wallet from Mt Gox, since my measly BTC balance is still in it and my coin apparently wasn't stolen?

Comment: Answer is no, not your keys not your coins. What have you been doing all these years? Now you're caring about it? It's too late.

Comment: Mt Gox became insolvent LONG ago, and the time period during which customers could make claims has long past. Sorry to say, your coins are likely long gone.

Comment: Yeah yeah, I know, I should have looked into it much sooner. Honestly my memory was faulty and I thought I had a miniscule fraction of one coin and wasn't too worried about it. I just happened to be cleaning up some really old emails, found the transfer notices and realized that I had more than I'd remembered - not a fortune, but enough to at least ask someone who knows more than I do :)

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know if there's a chance to get access to the wallet from Mt Gox, since my measly BTC balance is still in it and my coin apparently wasn't stolen?

This is not how things work with any centralized exchange. Particularly in this case, almost everything was seized and will be used to distribute money.

Lessons learnt for users and others: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/101959/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm not really fluent in the way BTC works, but when I put the address that my payments went to into the insight tool, it says the coins are still there. So what does that mean? 

If the balance of the payment address is still extant, doesn't that mean the fraction of a coin is still there and whoever has the private key for that address can access/transfer it?

I'll be honest, I'm only 90% sure my deposits were going into my Mt Gox account, and that's based on some very old automated emails I got from BTCMine.

Answer (score -3):

Mtgox was seized and your money is in the hands of the feds..
lesson learnt to stay away from centralised exchanges, they defeat bitcoins purpose.